# Convert json data to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I want to convert json data and put the return values into javascript array.
I use jquery version 1.9.1

jquery:

```
$('#searchinput').on('keyup', function(){
      $value2=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{{URL::to('search')}}',
        data: {'thesearch':decodeURIComponent($value2)},
        success:function(game){              
          alert(JSON.stringify(game));
        }
      });
    });
```

That gives the result:

```
[{"name":"First name"},{"name":"Second Name"}]
```

What I want is to store the values into javascript array like this:

```
var namearray = ['First name', 'Second Name'];
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you give a try using `map` function? You can do the following:

```
var nameArray = game.map(name => name["name"]);
```

So your whole code becomes like:

```
$('#searchinput').on('keyup', function(){
    $value2=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: '{{URL::to('search')}}',
      data: {'thesearch':decodeURIComponent($value2)},
      success:function(game){        
         var nameArray = game.map(name => name["name"]);
    }});
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: with JSON.parse(game) didn't work ..
So far it works that...
var nameArray = game.map(name => name["name"]);

Comment: updated my answer.My Upvote to your comment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `map` function:

```
var namearray = arr.map(x => x.name);
```

---

Link:

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the jquery map function

```
$.map([{"name":"First name"},{"name":"Second Name"}], function(val, i){return val.name})
```

read more about that http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/